# Javascript Code fails in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, cross-browser

```
function getSelectedRadio(seeker_provider) {
  var sign;
  for (var i=0; i<seeker_provider.length; i++) {
    if (seeker_provider[i].checked)
    {
      sign=i;
    }
  }
  if(sign==0)
  {
    alert(sign);
    window.location='updatcty.php';
  }
  if(sign==1)
  {
    alert(sign);
    window.location='../registration_provider.php?proid=2222221 & pagname=select';
  }
  // alert(document.all.seeker_provider.value);
}
```

I wrote this JavaScript function for getting the selected radio button value and redirect accordingly, but it supports all browsers except Firefox 3.0.6. What can I do?

Comment: What you can do is tell us what happens when you run that code in Firefox 3.0.6.

Comment: 1. Is it possible to see how you get seeker_provider?
2. You must define default value for sign.

Comment: Firefox has a handy javascript console: ctrl+shift+j. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
window.location='../registration_provider.php?proid=2222221 & pagname=select';
```

to this:

```
window.location='../registration_provider.php?proid=2222221&amp;pagname=select';
```

Comment: Why would that work? The url path doesn't use &amp; for escaping. If anything it should be %26, but that's not what he's trying to do either...

Comment: He's obviously trying to pass parameters in the querystring, which should be separated by &, which should be encoded as &amp;.

Regarding the answer, I'm making a best-effort guess considering the dearth of information. If the actual problem/solution is different I will "terminate" this answer.

Comment: When you want to pass the string, you need to encode: `name=Ben%26Jerry`. When you want a second parameter you shouldn't encode: `id=1&title=hello%20world`. Either way, `&amp;` is for HTML, not for url. Feel free to test it.